# async implementation with records and lock

Tags: async-await, c#-9.0

I am worried about a race condition situation in my code.

I have this function that fetches information from the database:

```
        public async Task ExecuteBroadcasts()
    {
        List<Broadcast> broadcasts =_iSMSFetcherUnitOfWork.GetAllBroadCastsInPastTimeThatDidntRun();

        foreach (Broadcast broadcast in broadcasts)
        {
            foreach (SenderPhone sender in broadcast.SenderPhoneList.SenderPhones)
            {
                foreach (ReceiverPhone receiverPhone in broadcast.RecipeintPhoneList.ReceiverPhones)
                { 
                   var tasks=  broadcast.RecipeintPhoneList.ReceiverPhones.Select(receiverPhone => _iSMSProcessorAndSender.ProcessSMSes(new PreProcessedSMS(sender.Phone, receiverPhone, broadcast.SMSTemplate))).ToArray();
                   await Task.WhenAll(tasks); 
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

This type 'PreProcessedSMS' is a record.  The ProcessSMSes is a function that sends the information fetched from the database to be sent through an SMS provider. Here is the content of this function.

```
 public async Task ProcessSMSes(PreProcessedSMS preProcessedSMS)
    { 
        _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.ReceiverPhone = preProcessedSMS.receiverPhoneObj;

        object sync = new object();

        string smsBody = string.Empty;

        lock (sync) smsBody = preProcessedSMS.sMSTemplate;

        Task longRunning = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        { 
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateSpinner(preProcessedSMS.sMSTemplate);
        });

        await longRunning.ContinueWith(async (sms) =>
        {
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateFirstName(smsBody);
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateLastName(smsBody);
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateCustom(smsBody);
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateUnsubscribe(smsBody);
            await _iSMSDispatcher.SendSMS(new SMSRecord(preProcessedSMS.senderPhone, preProcessedSMS.receiverPhoneObj.Phone, smsBody));

        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted); 

        longRunning.Start(); 
    }
```

I locked the 'smsBody' parameter from fear that there will be a next function execute that will set a different value for it. I am wary about the implementation. Whats the best way to execute the code efficiently while not encountering a possible race condition.

**update:**

```
  public async Task ProcessSMSes(PreProcessedSMS preProcessedSMS)
    {  
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.ReceiverPhone = preProcessedSMS.receiverPhoneObj;
            string smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateSpinner(preProcessedSMS.sMSTemplate);
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateFirstName(smsBody);
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateLastName(smsBody);
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateCustom(smsBody);
            smsBody = _iSMSExpressionInterpreter.TranslateUnsubscribe(smsBody);
            await _iSMSDispatcher.SendSMS(new SMSRecord(preProcessedSMS.senderPhone, preProcessedSMS.receiverPhoneObj.Phone, smsBody));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lock`s only work if everything else also uses the same `lock`. In this case, you're locking on a local variable, which will do nothing. You can't use a lock to protect against any other code changing anything. In this case, you *could* use `lock` in the implementation of `sMSTemplate` so that every time it's read/written, it uses a `lock`, but that seems very odd. I recommend using locks judiciously, where multithreaded access is *expected*, and not "from fear".

Side notes:

- [Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html); use `Task.Run` if you want to run code on a thread pool thread.
- [Don't use `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html); use `await` instead.

Comment: PreProcessedSMS is immutable since it is a record, I dont fear any race condition regarding its properties. About continue with, I read that it is a good idea to continue just after a task has finished. I am new to .Net concurrency, so I will implement the changes. By the way, I refer to your cookbook from time to time when I need help with concurrent code.

Comment: I put a different code in the update of my answer. PreProcessedSMS is a record so it is immutable.Could I encounter a situation of another thread modifying the smsBody inside the anonymous async function, while there is another thread inside? by the way, I read that using Task.Run is like starting a background thread. There may be 10 of thousands them created as I loop through all the SMSes that I have to send. Could it cause a problem?

Comment: One of the nice things about immutable records is that you don't have to worry about anything changing them, because they're immutable. Regarding the updated code, why do you need background threads at all?

Comment: I just want to fire and forget those smses. But I have no idea what repercussions it will cause in terms of memory and CPU.

Comment: There are no external references in the lambda condition in the updated code, so I dont see a chance for a race condition. I am thinking of removing the await  from this statement: await Task.Run(async () =>, or may be leave it and let the task return. I am not sure what implementation is better.

Comment: @LastGrip: Fire and forget is only appropriate if you accept "forget". I.e., if it's acceptable that the SMS messages are never sent. If you want to be sure the SMS messages are sent, then fire-and-forget is not a correct solution. It's better to either (a)wait for the SMS message to be sent from your controller action; or to use a [durable queue with a background service](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html).